# ModelForm won't validate because missing value, but model field has null=True

Tags: python, django

I have a problem where my `ModelForm` is trying to assign `''` to a field (it saves fine if I actually provide the primary key of the `Product`, but it's not a compulsory field, and won't save if the field is left blank). I take it that the ORM it's trying to set that field to `''`but:

- Shouldn't `''` be coerced to `None`, and;
- Why isn't the model form trying to set that field to `None` in the first place instead of
  `''`?

models.py

```
class Question(models.model):
    fk_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="product_question")
```

forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fk_product=forms.ChoiceField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['fk_product',]
```

The error:

> Cannot assign "''": "Question.fk_product" must be a "Product"
>   instance.

The view code that produces the error:

```
    QuestionModelFormset = modelformset_factory(Question,
                                form=QuestionForm,
                                extra=1)
    question_formset = QuestionModelFormset(
                            data=request.POST,
                            files=request.FILES,
                            queryset=Question.objects.all())
    if not question_formset.is_valid(): #error occurs on this line
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a `ChoiceField` for a foreign key. Use a `ModelChoiceField`. If you set `blank=True` on the model as @4140tm suggests, then the form will use a `ModelChoiceField` with `required=False`, so you can remove the line `    `fk_product=forms.ChoiceField(required=False)` from your form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `blank=True` too.

`null=True` means that this field is allowed to be NULL in database.

`blank=True` means it can be submitted without a value in forms. Otherwise it must have value.

Comment: You're right; I should have that there. However, updating and migrating doesn't make the validation error go away.

Comment: Try clearing the cache and if that doesn't solve it, restart the server. Shouldn't be necessary, but who knows. When I've had similar errors a simple page refresh has been enough.

Comment: Ah, sorry, ignore that comment; I had an old erroneous entry in my database that wouldn't validate. Works after deletion.